# LEFT OUTER JOIN with conditions (where, order by)?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm working on a Rails3 project with MySql (local) and Postgresql (Heroku) databases.
I need to put conditions on a LEFT OUTER JOIN but I don't know how.

I have 2 tables TRAININGS and TRAINING_HISTORIES.
I want to retrieve all the records of TRAININGS and add the last valid (aka finished) associated record of TRAINING_HISTORIES.

#### table TRAININGS

```
id  name  order_by
5   A     1  
6   B     2  
7   C     3
```

#### table TRAINING_HISTORIES

```
id  training_id finished_at score
43  5           2011-06-06  10
44  5           null        null
45  6           2011-07-07  11
46  6           2011-08-08  14
47  6           null        null
48  6           2011-09-09  18
49  6           null        null
50  7           null        null
51  7           2011-10-10  19
```

Here's my SQL query :

```
SELECT tc.id, tc.name, tc.order, 
th.id as history_id, th.finished_at, th.score
FROM trainings tc
LEFT OUTER JOIN training_histories th ON th.training_id = tc.id
WHERE tc.id > 4
AND tc.id < 8
GROUP BY tc.id
ORDER BY tc.order_by ASC, tc.id ASC
```

#### RESULTS I HAVE :

```
id  name  order history_id  finished_at score
5   A     1     43          2011-06-06  10
6   B     2     45          2011-07-07  11
7   C     3     50          null        null
```

- The query retrieve the first training_history for each join

#### RESULTS I NEED :

```
id  name  order history_id  finished_at score
5   A     1     43          2011-06-06  10
6   B     2     48          2011-09-09  18
7   C     3     51          2011-10-10  19
```

- In this scenario : it's the last finished training_history who's retrieved...

Any suggestions really appreciated !

Thank you

EDIT: If someone can answer on the Rails part, it could be great too ;-)
[How to Convert SQL Query to Rails Active Record Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016422/how-to-convert-sql-query-to-rails-active-record-query)

Comment: Might be easier in the long run and remove tricky bugs by using the same DBs in both development and production.

Comment: You need a subquery here to get the max finished value for each training ID, then join that subquery to the same table again to get the associated information for those rows. You can't do this with just simple joins; it may appear you are doing so, but you're not guaranteeing columns come from the right rows when grouped at all.

Comment: @Dan Grossman: Thx for the tip

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this Query, it would give you each training and the most recent training history for each one:

```
SELECT tc.id, tc.name, tc.order, 
th.id as history_id, th.finished_at, th.score
FROM trainings tc
LEFT OUTER JOIN training_histories th ON th.training_id = tc.id 
    and th.id =
    (SELECT th1.id from training_histories th1 where th1.training_id = tc.id
     and th1.finished_at is not null
     order by th1.finished_at desc limit 1)
WHERE tc.id > 4
AND tc.id < 8
GROUP BY tc.id
ORDER BY tc.order_by ASC, tc.id ASC
```

Comment: Also, check this thread I posted it, giving you good practices for doing this kinds of Queries :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656789/best-approach-get-the-most-recent-n-side-record-on-a-sql-query-on-a-n-1-relation

Comment: Thank you very much for your (really fast) answer! It's working perfectly. Also, I'll check your post on good practices... ;-)

Comment: This is not optimized at all. Just have a look at my answer, where I create a table with the newest dates and join it with the first table.

Comment: The most optimized way (and elegant) to do this is creating a View over training_histories with aggregation over the training_id returning only the record with the most recent finished_at timestamp. This way he would have all columns of training_history, not only the PK, FK and timestamp :)

Comment: It seems there's a lot of ways to perform my query... :-)

Comment: Always. @joakimdahlstrom's method should be preferred as the subquery only has to run once, where Everton's has to run for every row because it's a dependent subquery referencing the outer query. It can be a huge performance difference.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying your method is not right. My point is that is limited, since you would only get the timestamp from the training_histories table. It fits the given example, but usually you need to get more info about it. Thinking on performance, your method could be surely better, but it's worth testing :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure you can do

```
SELECT tc.id, tc.name, tc.order, 
th.id as history_id, th.finished_at, th.score
FROM trainings tc
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, training_id, MAX(finished_at) as finished_at, score 
    FROM training_histories GROUP BY training_id) th ON th.training_id = tc.id
WHERE tc.id > 4
AND tc.id < 8
GROUP BY tc.id
ORDER BY tc.order_by ASC, tc.id ASC
```

Comment: When I try your query I have a mysql error: "Unknown column 'th.finished_at' in 'field list'"... any ideas?

Comment: oh, yeah, sorry. You need `MAX(finished_at) as finished_at`. Updated the query.

Comment: no pb. The query is working now but the records are not what I expect. Indeed, only the first finished associated training_history is retrieve.

Comment: @Fro_oo, don't really understand what you mean. Can you explain what you get and how it differs from what you want?

Comment: well, in my post you can find "RESULTS I HAVE" and "RESULTS I NEED". The records returned by your query are the same as the results presented in "RESULTS I HAVE". But nevermind, the solution proposed by 'Everton Agner' is working. Thx for help anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Also in the where condition check for `finished_at not null` and add `Order by finished_at DESC`

```
SELECT tc.id, tc.name, tc.order, 
th.id as history_id, th.finished_at, th.score
FROM trainings tc
LEFT OUTER JOIN training_histories th ON th.training_id = tc.id
WHERE tc.id > 4
AND tc.id < 8
AND th.finished_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY tc.id
ORDER BY tc.order_by ASC, tc.id ASC, th.finished_at DESC
```

Comment: It's more complicated than that. You're not guaranteeing you'll pick the right non-null row for each tc.id when you collapse the groups. Just checking for nulls does not fix the true problem.

Comment: Thanks, but just for my understanding wont Order By th.finished_at DESC at the end help?

Comment: No, at that point you're ordering the groups, the wrong rows to represent the group have already been chosen. When you group by tc.id and use no aggregate functions on the other columns in the SELECT, MySQL is free to select any row's value when it collapses those rows into one per group. They may correspond to different rows, and are unlikely to all correspond to the desired latest row. You simply cannot resolve this query correctly without a subquery. This is invalid standard SQL as well; only MySQL allows you to do that, and its manual tells you about the ambiguity problem.