# How to rewrite this SQL query in Rails 3?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have two models, `submission` `has_many` `submissionstate`

and table `submissionstates` has the following columns:

```
id | submission_id | state_id | created_at
```

and the query is

```
SELECT submission_id, state_id
FROM submissionstates ss
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(created_at) as created_at
  FROM submissionstates ss
  GROUP BY submission_id
) x
ON ss.created_at = x.created_at
WHERE state_id = 0
```

Comment: the RoR documentation on queries should help you http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Refer to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016422/how-to-convert-sql-query-to-rails-active-record-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like the link Saurabh gave, you end up putting your sql fragments into the rails query methods; something like this

```
list = SubmissionState.select("submission_id, state_id")
  .where(:state_id => 0)
  .joins("
    JOIN (
      SELECT MAX(created_at) as created_at
      FROM submissionstates ss
      GROUP BY submission_id
    ) x
    ON ss.created_at = x.created_at
  ")

puts list.length
```

to be honest at this point you might be better off just using find_by_sql

```
sql = "
  SELECT submission_id, state_id
  FROM submissionstates ss
  JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(created_at) as created_at
    FROM submissionstates ss
    GROUP BY submission_id
  ) x
  ON ss.created_at = x.created_at
  WHERE state_id = ?
  AND some_other_value = ?
"

list = SubmissionState.find_by_sql([sql, 0, 'something-else'])
puts list.length
```

NOTE: once you start using joins or find_by_sql rails acts like it gives you objects back but really they will contain any attributes defined in the select clause and find_by_sql returns all attributes as strings which can be annoying

Comment: hmm.. I am just wondering, which one is more efficient? `find_by_sql` or `Active Record Query Interface`?

Comment: "I am just wondering, which one is more efficient?" > my guess is there are about the same - you can drop down to a lower level and get back a hash instead - http://blog.daniel-azuma.com/archives/216